# Flotr printing problem with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: printing, graph, internet-explorer-8, flot

I can't seem to print a flotr graph with internet explorer 8. With Firefox it works.

I'm currently using revision 173 of flotr because there was a fix for printing in a previous revision.

I have a hunch that the problem is related to the fact that canvas isn't really supported by ie8. Flotr uses excanvas to emulate canvas...

If flotr can't be printed with Internet Explorer 8, that can't be very practical...

Thank you for your suggestions/help.

Comment: Never used flotr, but you're right: IE8 doesn't support canvas, so they will be using a hack to emulate it which will very likely break printing. Can't really make any suggestions, other than to use a Firefox, Chrome, Safari or Opera. Or if you're feeling brave, try IE9beta, which does support Canvas.

Comment: Here's the catch, I've developing a web app and forcing my users to not use Internet Explorer 8 is not an option. Thx for the ie9 tip. But I heard that only works with vista/windows 7

Answer (score 0):

After having a hard time finding information about this. It looks like revision 173 works in the end... fyi.